# Django / Geodjango / Raster / geotiff: Problems with practice task

Tags: python, django, raster, gdal, geodjango

I got a practice task, which I can not get any further. 
The task is the following:

> Project Description The goal of the projects is to create a map view
>   similar to the Google Maps, where the user can see some imagery data
>   captured by drones.
>
> User should be able to move around the map freely, as well as zoom in
>   and zoom out to take a closer look at the captured imagery data.
>
> It is strongly desired that the served imagery data will support
>   transparency while minimizing the file size and bandwidth usage. This
>   does not have to be implemented, but solution ideas are welcomed.
>
> The raw imagery data will be provided as GeoTIFF files. Imagery
>   visible on the map can be added by placing a file inside a directory
>   that is read by the server. Project Delivery Method
>
> Project should be delivered as a Git repository with documentation
>   required to setup and run the project.
>
> Requirements
>   1. Server implementation in Python 3.5+
>   2. Project must be able to run on Ubuntu Server 16.04
>   3. Optimal disk space usage for imagery data displayed to the user (as the app may be processing terabytes of satellite imagery data)
>   4. Relatively conservative bandwidth usage
>
> Notes:
>   1. The project will be deployed on a machine that is already running other Python software. Dependency conflicts must be avoided.
>   (virtualenv, Docker)
>   2. The UI can be a simple HTML page with embedded libraries and inline scripts.

In addition, it was specified in an e-mail:

> "The test task is not code but just the approach and rough app
>   architecture
>
> ```I'm attaching a tank spec. Like I've mentioned. I'm more interested
>   in problem-solving and your ideas. I expect a working prototype tough.
>
> Use any libraries you wish to use. Create an elegant, easy to
>   understand the solution. You can use as much time as you want. Would be
>   great if you could deliver the code by git.... ```"

So far I have done:

1. Ubuntu as VM
2. Venv
3. Postgres and PostGIS installed (Django writes error-free in a database)
4. Django project and app created
5. Documentation up to this point

I have now integrated the geotiff via console and that seems to work too:

```
from django.contrib.gis.gdal import GDALRaster
raster = GDALRaster('base/static/base/geotiff/xto-site3-rgb.tif')
raster.name
Out[4]: 'base/static/base/geotiff/xto-site3-rgb.tif'
raster.width, raster.height
Out[5]: (23001, 9668)
```

In the models.py is so far:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models


class RasterBase(models.Model):
    raster = models.RasterField()
    name = models.TextField()
```

How does it work that I install the grid so that I can portray this in an html similar to google maps? If I understand correctly, I must now write the geotiff in the database, and read on from there, right?

Unfortunately, I find in the network largely only outdated stuff, or often examples, which is assumed by shapefiles. Should I convert the grid to a shapefile and continue like that?

So far, I only make small things in Django, like my own blog and a few statistics, but this with Geodjango is a bit fierce because I have to give it up, as it were tomorrow. Latest Tuesday morning.

I would be very grateful if someone could give me some tips. All in all, that's pretty important to me, and it would be a shame if I messed up half of the task (or the last third) of the task.

- Django is version 2.0
- The GeoTIFF ~900mb

Thanks for all. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but maybe some people are searching for a solution here.

When you want to display geodata on a map, you can use a WebGIS framework like   [Openlayers](https://openlayers.org/) or [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/). They provide all the functionality to move the map and zoom in / out.

I would not recommend to store large raster data in a database. You can serve it directly from a file server via a TileLayer or use a XYZ tiling structure to minimize the bandwidth usage.

Openlayers has a lot of [examples](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/index.html?q=cog) on how to server GeoTiff files.